# MySQL Showing SQL Syntax Error when run from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a dynamic page and store it in a MySQL database. It connects to the database fine, but there seems to be an error in the SQL Syntax that I can't find. I've tried reformatting the code and cannot pin point it.
Here's the PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            $dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'test_db')
            or die("There was an error connecting to the database. Please try again later.");

            $fullname = (string)$_POST['name'];
            $guest_email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            echo "<h1>Thanks for your submission!</h1>";
            echo "Your Name on File is: ". $fullname . '<br>';
            echo "Your Email on File is: ". $guest_email . '<br>';
            echo "Your Password on File is: ". $password . '<br>';

            $add_query = "INSERT INTO test_form (full_name, email, user_pass) VALUES( $fullname, $guest_email, $password)";

            $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $add_query)
            or die("<strong>There was an error processing the form. Please call your IT support!</strong>". mysqli_error($dbc));

            mysqli_close($dbc);
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test Form</h1>
        <form action="index.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name"/>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"/>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter a password"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're dealing with strings; quote them.

Comment: This is the SQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Doe , johklasd@me.com , alkisefdlkje)' at line 1

Comment: I know the error quite well ;-)

Comment: `('$fullname', '$guest_email', '$password')` <= fixed ;-) but don't store passwords in plain text. You will get hacked.

Comment: You're welcome John.

Comment: lol I noticed you posted an answer John, as I did too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote your values when it comes to strings

```
('$fullname', '$guest_email', '$password')
```

**Important note about password storage:**

I noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged and if used on a live site, you will get hacked.

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

If and when you do use one of those, make sure the column is long enough to accomodate the hash.

Plus, in regards to SQL injection which you are presently open to,  [**use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Answer (score 0):

In `$add_query`, you're not concatenating the other variables correctly, like you did before. This should work :

```
$add_query = "INSERT INTO test_form (full_name, email, user_pass) VALUES ( '" . $fullname . "' , '" . $guest_email . "' , '" . $password . "')";
```

Comment: `( " . $fullname . " , " . $guest_email . " , " . $password . ")` This will also fail. We're dealing with strings.

Comment: It did fail. How would I quote post values?

Comment: It's still coming up as failed. They're all VARCHAR fields, would that happen to have anything to do with it? It runs fine when I run it through SQLPro with a plain string.

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware of the fact that your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection, so it must not be used in 'real world' environments but for testing only!

To prevent SQL Injections from the beginning you can use Prepared Statements as described in the docs:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

I am not familar with the mysqli driver and would recommend to use PDO, which is a more generic approach for database connection.

However, your code with mysqli prepared statements should look like this:

```
<?php
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'test_db')
or die("There was an error connecting to the database. Please try again later.");

$fullname = (string)$_POST['name'];
$guest_email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
echo "<h1>Thanks for your submission!</h1>";
echo "Your Name on File is: ". $fullname . '<br>';
echo "Your Email on File is: ". $guest_email . '<br>';
//echo "Your Password on File is: ". $password . '<br>'; // never ever print any password!

/* create prepared statement */
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, "INSERT INTO test_form (full_name, email, user_pass) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");

/* bind params to prepared statement */
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss', $fullname, $guest_email, $password);

/* execute prepared statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

/* close statement and connection */
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($dbc);
```

?>